# SQL max with additional column

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select a latest record from MySQL table using MAX. Date column that I apply MAX to is selected properly, but second column the ID is not. Following screenshot expalins this best:[image]

As you see 1_2018 is selected instead of 15_2018.

Comment: This is basically a MySQL weirdness. Any other DBMS (or even MySQL itself if you change the default settings) will just throw a proper error message. The thing is that `1_2018` is just an arbitrary value (not even random).

Comment: I don't see any weirdness here. He selects the max value and mysql returns the max value.

Comment: why error message? is there anything wrong with this query?

Comment: @jarosik yes, there is. You don't get the corresponding other columns when you select like this. I'll post an answer in a minute.

Comment: any column in `SELECT` should either be in aggregate function or part of a `GROUP BY`

Comment: What if there is a created & year_id with date of 2019? do you think there will only date with 2018?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use your query as a sub query to pick the row(s) for max created value

```
select *
from business_trip
where created = (
    select max(created )
    from business_trip
    where year_id LIKE '%_2018'
)
```

Comment: What if there is a `created & year_id` with date of 2019?

Comment: @Sinto max(created) will be picked based on filter `year_id LIKE '%_2018'` as per OP's logic so what ever date comes out will be max data for the filter, the issue was not getting correct `year_id` as compared to max(created)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT created, year_id
FROM business_trip 
WHERE created = (SELECT MAX(created) FROM business_trip);
```

In this case I'm here using sub query to satisfy your requirement. Other answers used `ORDER BY` (which will not give the expected answer until the year_id is MAX) and other with `MAX()` in `SELECT` will not pull the related record with latest `created` value.
In my query I'm also avoided use of check over `year_id` so this will always return you the record with latest `created` value.

Comment: @CalebKleveter: yes, thank you noting me. i have added my comment

Answer (score -1):

you can sort by the `created` and then `LIMIT 1` to get only a single record. Something like this

```
SELECT created,year_id
FROM business_trip 
WHERE year_id LIKE '%_2018'
ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 1;
```